# Testfor command for player deaths

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So my friends and I are building a Minecraft server with TDM, CTF, and FFA. My job is to make it so that when a player dies, they will respawn with x items. Using the Halocraft mod, the loadout system when starting looks like this:

```
testfor @a[r=500] > clear @a > give @a 4534 > give @a 4537 > give @a 4515 64 > give @a 4516 24 > more give @a commands for armor.
```

After the clear, all players receive an Assault Rifle, Magnum, along with 64 extra rounds for the AR, and 24 Magnum rounds.

We need a separate system to detect a player death, then clear said player's inventory, and give all new gear. How would you do that?

Comment: @Skylinerw not really a duplicate of that question, as that's for singleplayer, this is for server commands

Comment: @Alex They are the same question. As well, the other question directly states multiple players are involved, thus both are requesting for multiplayer.

Comment: I've tried that and it doesn't exactly work for our needs. That's more of a one-time deal, it seems. Ours needs to be used over and over. I don't think the other one has that capability.

Comment: A common way this is handled is by setting the player's spawn point on a pressure plate triggering a chain of command blocks, and then teleports them to a respawn point after inventory is reset. This type of solution can also be adjusted for, say, classes and teams, whereas a "testfor death" sort of solution is harder to sort out

Comment: Not a bad idea. We'll give that a try.